# Object not found in for loop?

Tags: r

Here is the function I am using

```
R0 <- function(beta, gamma, N)
{
  product <- beta*N/gamma
  return(product)
}
```

And here is the for loop I'm using it in

```
gamma1 <- seq(0.1,2,0.1)
n <- 20
y <- numeric(length(gamma1))
for(i in i:n)
{
  y[i] <- R0(0.1, gamma1[i], 100)
}
plot(y,gamma1)
```

The function works by itself but whenever I try and run the for loop I get an error "Error in i : object 'i' not found" and can't figure out why.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is here `i:n`, it should be `1:20` if you want `i` to have values from 1 to 20.

Comment: It makes more sense to put that thank you although it still doesn't work when I changed it.

Comment: You don't need a loop as your function is vectorized, use `y <- R0(0.1, gamma1, 100)`

Comment: The loop is working for me now, what doesn't work for you? You should follow Clemsang comment though.

Comment: Same for me, loop is working